# Does nearPoints() and brushedPoints() functions in Shiny work on bar-graphs?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use `nearPoints()` function in Shiny with bar-graphs(both basic and `ggplot` packages). But when the page is rendered, none of the `click, dbclick, hover` are not working with the bar-graphs.

My aim is to show either a `dataTable` or `verbatimTextOutput` (containing the rows of the clicked bar) when a bar on the bar-graph is clicked. I can do the above mentioned operations on a scattered plot but not on a bar graph.

The examples mentioned in the [Shiny documentation page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selecting-rows-of-data.html) only showed the scattered plots examples. I just want to know if the `nearPoints()` and `brushedPoints()` (similar function for a range on the plot) functions work with bar-graphs or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Winston Chang replied to the question in Shiny Apps discussion forum on Google groups. I am posting it here for future references. Here is the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/shiny-discuss/dTywKfh4XCo/L3Upb1Wj_3UJ)